# How to retrieve just the names from a list of values containing numbers and names?

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, dictionary

I have a name list with numbers. I want to write the names in the text file. But I am not able to remove these numbers.

```
print ("node_result[0]")
print (node_result[0])
print ("node_result[1]")
print (node_result[1])

for i in range(0, len(nodeName)):
    temp=str(node_result[i])
    if not node_result[i] == {}:
        dosya.write(nodeName[i] + ":  ")
        dosya.write(temp)
        dosya.write('\n')

dosya.close()
```

The list below is the output of the above print commands:

```
node_result[0]
{32: 'Konstantinos'}
node_result[1]
{32: 'Silvija', 33: 'John', 34: 'Micheal'}
```

How to get these names without the numbers?

Comment: It seems like every every item in `node_result` is a whole dictionary... try this: `node_result[0][32]` and see what comes out.

Comment: Yes, It works. But the index 32. It s changeable. How can show node_result[0] without second index?

Comment: I want to see->  node_result[1]
{'Silvija', 'John', 'Micheal'}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a=[{32: 'Konstantinos'},{32: 'Silvija', 33: 'John', 34: 'Micheal'}]
name_list=[]
for i in a:
    for j in i.values():
        name_list.append(j)
print (name_list)
```

the result will be:

> ['Konstantinos', 'Silvija', 'John', 'Micheal']

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
# utility function to flatten a list of lists
flatten = lambda l: [item for sublist in l for item in sublist]

# define your test data
node_result = [
    {32: 'Konstantinos'},
    {32: 'Silvija', 33: 'John', 34: 'Micheal'}]

# fetch names and flatten results
names = flatten([d.values() for d in node_result])
# => ['Konstantinos', 'Silvija', 'John', 'Micheal']
```

If you want to preserve the information which names belonged to one `node_result` item you can omit the invocation of `flatten`

```
names = [d.values() for d in node_result]
# => [['Konstantinos'], ['Silvija', 'John', 'Micheal']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Each element of node_result is a full dictionary. To get only dictionary values, call `.values()`:

```
for i in range(0, len(nodeResult)):
    if not node_result[i] == {}:
        print(node_result[i].values())
```

`.values()` returns a list with all values for a given index of `node_result`.

Comment: Thank you :) That's work. I am new on Python. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @MuhammetBolat: Would you please accept this as answer and upvote it? Thanks!!